# Moved from self-hosted blog to Wordpress.com Blog. How to Redirect?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I've managed to move all the content from my self hosted wordpress blog to wordpress.com but I can't seem to figure out how to setup .htaccess wildcard redirects from the old posts showing up in google to the same post on the new blog.

I can setup category redirects fine as below:

```
Redirect 301 /category/general/ https://reverbstudios.wordpress.com/category/general/
```

And even redirect individual posts the same way:

```
Redirect 301 /67/web-design-leitrim/ https://reverbstudios.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/web-design-leitrim/
```

You'll notice with the individual post redirect, I had a permalink structure that just added a random number before the post title. So my problem is is there any way to setup a wild card redirect that redirects any google result for individual blog posts to their new url or at least get them onto the new blog home page url!??

Leon

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it should redirect everything after the domain name to the exact same URL on the new domain:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://reverbstudios.wordpress.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```